# Should I use Enumeration or Class stereotype in UML to represent a type directory table?

Tags: class, enums, uml, data-modeling

Let's take 2 UML class model entities: One represents an actual Order and another represents an Orede Type. Any Order corresponds to one Type. A 2-way-naviglabe many Orders to one Type  relation is meant. Order Type instances are, for example, "Request availability", "Request price", "Preorder", "Buy", "Cancel", "Request support", etc. Order Types are to be addable and editable in the resulting application. Should I model Order Type as Class or as Enumeration? From the data perspective I can't see the difference actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer an enumeration. Classes should define properties and **behaviour**. In this case the type represents only a value with no need of methods.

Conclusion:

The usage of a class would surely possible but not necessary if you only want to represent values. Also, it would create a lot of extra coding work. You would have to write and maintain a bunch of classes that only represent one value when you could use an enumeration, which is surely the best and shortes way to represent typed values.